# sendmmsg() return -1, no buffer space available, why does memset solve this?

Tags: c, sockets, memset

One of these three members in `struct mmsghdr`:

```
void         *msg_control;    /* ancillary data, see below */
size_t        msg_controllen; /* ancillary data buffer len */
int           msg_flags;      /* flags on received message */
```

causing the problem: `sendmmsg()` returns -1, "no buffer space available".

After `memset(&(Msgs),0,sizeof(struct mmsghdr));` problem goes away.
One of man pages said `msg_flags` is ignored, so is `msg_control` messing things up?

Comment: What about `msg_controllen`? Maybe it happened to contain an arbitrarily large garbage value.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It seems you are saying when you don't set the `Msgs` fields explicitly then you get an error. That would be unsurprising. But without a complete code example it is impossible to say exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason but in general it doesn't seem surprising that something fails if **input** arguments are left **uninitialized!** In this case it may be sufficient to set `msg_controllen` to zero but in general it seems better to initialize all input arguments.

Comment: @kaylum I can't provide the code example as the similar code structure(this is why I wondered several hours this afternoon, same chunk code perfectly fine just different position in the source file) will produce different stack layout by the compiler, and I don't have the "permission" to put whole code out, so no. And the main reason I post it as a problem is very few people will ever use sendmmsg() syscall and maybe tell them initing mmsghdr IS NECESSARY, and my reputation can't let me just add this to a similar problem involving sendmsg(). The man pages sometimes explain things very badly.

Comment: You were not asked to put your whole code in. You were requested to give a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please read the link to understand what that means. And if you want to continue on Stackoverflow please read some of the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) pages to understand what the post requirements are.

Comment: @kaylum I don't have time to CONSTRUCT another buggy code just for my sakes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have taken local variable of this structure.
By default local variables are initialized with garbage causing this issue.
You can even try this by having global variable of the same.

Comment: This is true, reasons above. But bad advice, just init it you'll be fine.